# Why is there a deadlock between two parallel executions of identical transactions?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have an application that uses an SQL transaction to make updates to the msdb database on SQL Server. This transaction is executed periodically, at irregular intervals. SQL Server 2012 (SP4) is used. After a while, SQL Server reports deadlocks on msdb.dbo.backupset table, and the only participants are the processes that execute the mentioned SQL transaction

Below is a functional example of the transaction, having the arguments replaced with example values so that it can be readily executed on msdb. The application passes new arguments with each call of the transaction.

```
BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 3498233
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 378880

SELECT @LogDevName = name
FROM master..sysdevices AS sdev
WHERE phyname = @BackupFileName

SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount'

IF @SqlVersion > 9  -- 2008+
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + N', compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize'
    END
SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@MediaFamilyCount int, @BackupFileNumber int, @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0), @MediaSetId int', @BackupFileNumber = @BackupFileNumber,@MediaFamilyCount = @MediaFamilyCount, @CompressedSize = @CompressedSize, @MediaSetId = @MediaSetId    

UPDATE bms
    SET media_family_count = @MediaFamilyCount, mirror_count = @MirrorCount
    FROM msdb..backupmediaset AS bms
    WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId
    
 -- All bmf's

SET @FamilySequenceNumber = 1
SET @BackupFileName = N'\\testcase\Test_TLog_20211121180001.trn'
SET @Mirror = 0

UPDATE bmf
    SET bmf.physical_device_name = @BackupFileName
    FROM msdb..backupmediafamily AS bmf
    WHERE     bmf.media_set_id           = @MediaSetId
          AND bmf.family_sequence_number = @FamilySequenceNumber
          AND bmf.mirror                 = @Mirror
          
UPDATE bmf
    SET bmf.logical_device_name = @LogDevName
    FROM msdb..backupmediafamily AS bmf
    WHERE     bmf.media_set_id           = @MediaSetId
          AND bmf.family_sequence_number = @FamilySequenceNumber
          AND bmf.mirror                 = @Mirror

SET @MaxFamilySequence = 1

DELETE FROM msdb..backupmediafamily WITH (ROWLOCK)
WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId AND family_sequence_number > @MaxFamilySequence

COMMIT TRAN UpdateMediaTables
```

Here is the xml for the deadlock graph:

```
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="process2d890c8"/>
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="process2d890c8" taskpriority="-5" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 4:1:8623 " waittime="1550" ownerId="1566457106" transactionname="UpdateMediaTables" lasttranstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:05.697" XDES="0xb16d09b80" lockMode="U" schedulerid="8" kpid="19856" status="suspended" spid="488" sbid="0" ecid="5" priority="5" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:05.660" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-21T15:00:05.633" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.633" clientapp="Demo" hostname="AA-SQL1" hostpid="14200" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1566457106" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="190" sqlhandle="0x020000000aac851a57d841f58dc63ba4bbe4b4059b68c6ab0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount, compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId    </frame>
                <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="36" stmtstart="1996" stmtend="2528" sqlhandle="0x02000000a5af092360e1ef5edb55dab1b8cfba609a9b02e50000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@MediaFamilyCount int, @BackupFileNumber int, @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0), @MediaSetId int', @BackupFileNumber = @BackupFileNumber,@MediaFamilyCount = @MediaFamilyCount, @CompressedSize = @CompressedSize, @MediaSetId = @MediaSetId    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 566952
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 156160

SELECT @LogDevName = name
FROM master..sysdevices AS sdev
WHERE phyname = @BackupFileName

SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount'

IF @SqlVersion &gt; 9  -- 2008+
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + N', compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize'
    END
SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2daa928" taskpriority="-5" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 4:1:9263 " waittime="1550" ownerId="1566457106" transactionname="UpdateMediaTables" lasttranstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:05.697" XDES="0x14b82acbd0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="8248" status="suspended" spid="488" sbid="0" ecid="6" priority="5" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:05.660" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-21T15:00:05.633" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.633" clientapp="Demo" hostname="AA-SQL1" hostpid="14200" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1566457106" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="190" sqlhandle="0x020000000aac851a57d841f58dc63ba4bbe4b4059b68c6ab0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount, compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId    </frame>
                <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="36" stmtstart="1996" stmtend="2528" sqlhandle="0x02000000a5af092360e1ef5edb55dab1b8cfba609a9b02e50000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@MediaFamilyCount int, @BackupFileNumber int, @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0), @MediaSetId int', @BackupFileNumber = @BackupFileNumber,@MediaFamilyCount = @MediaFamilyCount, @CompressedSize = @CompressedSize, @MediaSetId = @MediaSetId    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 566952
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 156160

SELECT @LogDevName = name
FROM master..sysdevices AS sdev
WHERE phyname = @BackupFileName

SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount'

IF @SqlVersion &gt; 9  -- 2008+
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + N', compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize'
    END
SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2bb4558" taskpriority="-5" logused="328" waitresource="PAGE: 4:1:9263 " waittime="948" ownerId="1566456428" transactionname="UpdateMediaTables" lasttranstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.410" XDES="0x14981ffb80" lockMode="U" schedulerid="7" kpid="19408" status="suspended" spid="470" sbid="0" ecid="7" priority="5" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.393" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.393" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.393" clientapp="Demo" hostname="AA-SQL1" hostpid="14732" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1566456428" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="190" sqlhandle="0x020000000aac851a57d841f58dc63ba4bbe4b4059b68c6ab0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount, compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId    </frame>
                <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="36" stmtstart="1996" stmtend="2528" sqlhandle="0x02000000a9093d2c0a0d22ed2f73dc20e182fd1d912553b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@MediaFamilyCount int, @BackupFileNumber int, @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0), @MediaSetId int', @BackupFileNumber = @BackupFileNumber,@MediaFamilyCount = @MediaFamilyCount, @CompressedSize = @CompressedSize, @MediaSetId = @MediaSetId    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 566948
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 259072

SELECT @LogDevName = name
FROM master..sysdevices AS sdev
WHERE phyname = @BackupFileName

SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount'

IF @SqlVersion &gt; 9  -- 2008+
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + N', compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize'
    END
SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process2daacf8" taskpriority="-5" logused="328" waitresource="PAGE: 4:1:8623 " waittime="972" ownerId="1566456428" transactionname="UpdateMediaTables" lasttranstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.410" XDES="0x14b82ace80" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="7048" status="suspended" spid="470" sbid="0" ecid="4" priority="5" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.393" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.393" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.393" clientapp="Demo" hostname="AA-SQL1" hostpid="14732" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1566456428" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="190" sqlhandle="0x020000000aac851a57d841f58dc63ba4bbe4b4059b68c6ab0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount, compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId    </frame>
                <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="36" stmtstart="1996" stmtend="2528" sqlhandle="0x02000000a9093d2c0a0d22ed2f73dc20e182fd1d912553b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@MediaFamilyCount int, @BackupFileNumber int, @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0), @MediaSetId int', @BackupFileNumber = @BackupFileNumber,@MediaFamilyCount = @MediaFamilyCount, @CompressedSize = @CompressedSize, @MediaSetId = @MediaSetId    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 566948
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 259072

SELECT @LogDevName = name
FROM master..sysdevices AS sdev
WHERE phyname = @BackupFileName

SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount'

IF @SqlVersion &gt; 9  -- 2008+
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + N', compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize'
    END
SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,    </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="process12ee786188" taskpriority="-5" logused="10000" waittime="730" schedulerid="12" kpid="1808" status="suspended" spid="470" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="5" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.393" lastbatchcompleted="2021-12-21T15:00:04.393" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.393" clientapp="Demo" hostname="AA-SQL1" hostpid="14732" loginname="DEMO\test" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="1566456428" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="190" sqlhandle="0x020000000aac851a57d841f58dc63ba4bbe4b4059b68c6ab0000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount, compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId    </frame>
                <frame procname="mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_executesql" line="1" stmtstart="-1" sqlhandle="0x0400ff7f427f99d9010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
sp_executesql    </frame>
                <frame procname="adhoc" line="36" stmtstart="1996" stmtend="2528" sqlhandle="0x02000000a9093d2c0a0d22ed2f73dc20e182fd1d912553b10000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@MediaFamilyCount int, @BackupFileNumber int, @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0), @MediaSetId int', @BackupFileNumber = @BackupFileNumber,@MediaFamilyCount = @MediaFamilyCount, @CompressedSize = @CompressedSize, @MediaSetId = @MediaSetId    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>
BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables

DECLARE @SqlVersion int
DECLARE @LogDevName nvarchar(512)
DECLARE @MediaSetId int
DECLARE @FamilySequenceNumber tinyint
DECLARE @MaxFamilySequence tinyint
DECLARE @Mirror tinyint
DECLARE @BackupFileName nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @BackupFileNumber int
DECLARE @MediaFamilyCount int
DECLARE @MirrorCount int
DECLARE @CompressedSize numeric(20, 0)
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @SqlVersion = @@microsoftversion / 0x1000000
SET @MediaSetId = 566948
SET @BackupFileNumber = 1
SET @MediaFamilyCount = 1
SET @MirrorCount = 1
SET @CompressedSize = 259072

SELECT @LogDevName = name
FROM master..sysdevices AS sdev
WHERE phyname = @BackupFileName

SET @sql = N'UPDATE bs SET position = @BackupFileNumber, last_family_number = @MediaFamilyCount'

IF @SqlVersion &gt; 9  -- 2008+
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + N', compressed_backup_size = @CompressedSize'
    END
SET @sql = @sql + N' FROM msdb..backupset AS bs
            WHERE media_set_id = @MediaSetId'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,    </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="8623" dbid="4" subresource="FULL" objectname="msdb.dbo.backupset" id="lock5e1d530780" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594045595648">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process12ee786188" mode="U"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2d890c8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </pagelock>
        <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="9263" dbid="4" subresource="FULL" objectname="msdb.dbo.backupset" id="lockf1b4c0980" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594045595648">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process12ee786188" mode="U"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2daa928" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </pagelock>
        <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="9263" dbid="4" subresource="FULL" objectname="msdb.dbo.backupset" id="lockf1b4c0980" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594045595648">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2daa928" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2bb4558" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </pagelock>
        <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="8623" dbid="4" subresource="FULL" objectname="msdb.dbo.backupset" id="lock5e1d530780" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594045595648">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2d890c8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process2daacf8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </pagelock>
        <exchangeEvent id="Pipe25c250400" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="2">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="process2daacf8"/>
                <owner id="process2bb4558"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="process12ee786188"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </exchangeEvent>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

[image]

I don't see how this situation could lead to a deadlock. Even if the two processes coincide in parallel, the two transactions are identical and therefore execute their queries in the same sequential order. Furthermore, the query that updates the backupset table doesn't have who to deadlock with, since it is the only one in the entire transaction that queries this table. Lock yes, but not deadlock. Can someone please help me understand how this deadlock situation is possible?

Comment: Guessing you probably need to add an index on `msdb..backupset (media_set_id)`. And you might want a `ROWLOCK` hint on that query (the one in the dynamic SQL). Side point: dynamic SQL variables should always be declared as `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: `msdb..backupset (media_set_id)` already has an index. I do agree with @Charlieface that it would help if you were to set rowlock hints. The reason deadlocks are happening is that you have a race condition on page locks, where both processes acquire locks on the pages the other process needs. You can see this at the bottom of the XML you included ( see `<resource-list>` node). Assuming that you never update the same `MediaSetId ` in parallel, ROWLOCKs should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of diagnosing this one, I would just hit the "easy button", and serialize the transactions with an application lock:

```
BEGIN TRAN UpdateMediaTables
exec sp_getapplock 'UpdateMediaTables', 'Exclusive'
. . .
```

Then the second session will be blocked *before acquiring any locks* until the first is complete.

Comment: This will work great for that situation. It helps a lot, many thanks